# Are there any sites where selenium doesn't work?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am a Korean college student living in Korea.
I'm asking this question using a translator because there's no one around me to ask.

Is there a site where selenium xpath is not applied?
Syntax 'find_element_by_xpath' is not applied.
The same was true when setting another xpath or replacing xpath with a name or id.

It makes an error as if it can't find the xpath.

What's even more strange is that 'find_element_by_xpath' worked fine on other sites.
I wonder why this phenomenon is happening.
Two days of experiments.
I didn't make any mistakes.

Comment: xpath is a technology, selenium usage xpath v1.0, can you show us the website where xpath didn't work ?

Comment: https://sugang.gwnu.ac.kr/     This is the school  class registration website.  It's for research purposes.
I'm a graduating class, so there's no reason to abuse it.

Comment: sorry I did not abuse you. also I have given you a solution below, do try it out and let me know if you run into any issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think question heading in misleading,

you can use xpath as well as Selenium.

only thing is, it is inside an iframe.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get("https://sugang.gwnu.ac.kr/")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "Main")))
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "id"))).send_keys('your user name')
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: I don't know the information about the module, but I think I know the meaning of the function roughly.
I succeeded in logging in automatically, but the problem is next.
<li onclick="fnLoad('/sugang?attribute=sugangMain',this.id);" id="menu_sugang"> == $0
The above contents
'wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "menu_sugang"))).I tried with the 'click()' syntax, but there was an error.
I thought it was an iframe issue, so I added the phrase 'wait.until (EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it ((By.XPATH,//*[@id="Main"])), but the same error occurred.

Comment: I'm very stressed because I don't know the cause even when I look up the Internet. I would be very much obliged to you if you would help me. Also, I want to know how to refer to it or learn it myself.

Comment: Sure, seems like these are new issues, Can you create new ticket by new ticket I mean new question post. Community will be happy to help you.

Comment: ok I'll try it . I want you to respond.

Comment: @옵저버 : Sure thing

Comment: sorry i'm little headache. You have updated your new question with an answer.

Comment: No, I have not, I need to have credentials to look further.

Comment: Can I know specifically what credit is? Are you talking about my id and pw?

Comment: don't know how to contact you personally in stackoverflow, so if you let me know your email, I will send you id and pw.

Comment: I don't mind disclosing it, but I ask for your understanding because if you use it, it can cause harm to other people and the problem can come to me.

Comment: I sent ID and pw by email. I look forward to your kind help