# How do I run the button on the next page of iframe with selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

Previous Questions
[Are there any sites where selenium doesn't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68862100/are-there-any-sites-where-selenium-doesnt-work/68862579?noredirect=1#comment121714031_68862579)

```
driver.get("https://sugang.gwnu.ac.kr/")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
time.sleep(2)
driver.switch_to.frame("Main")
# wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="Main"]')))
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "id"))).send_keys('my id')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "pwd"))).send_keys('my pwd')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "btn_login"))).click()
```

> Up to this point, it works normally. (id and pwd are personal information, so I deleted them.)

```
# time.sleep(2)
# driver.switch_to.frame("Main")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "menu_sugang"))).click()
```

> It turned into a new window and didn't work from here. iframe is still the 'Main'.

```
<iframe name="Main" id="Main" style="position: absolute; width:100%; height:100%; border: none;" scrolling="auto"></iframe>


<li onclick="fnLoad('/sugangattribute=sugangMain',this.id);"id="menu_sugang">
                    <imgsrc="/resources/img/layout/icon-registration.png">
                    <span>수강신청</span>
                </li>
```

> I tried to click on the html syntax above, but it didn't work.

I read an automation book, but it was really hard because this information was not even in the book.
There was also googling, but there was a limit to the term problem. At first, I didn't even know iframe existed.
There are many great teachers here, but I want to know materials or ways to learn by myself.

Comment: so basically you are saying you could login, but in the dashboard page you see `menu_sugang` and you cannot click on that ?

Comment: Exactly I think we need to approach it in a different way.
To avoid misunderstanding, it is never a way to open with a new tab or window. @cruisepandey

Comment: It's difficult to imagine without seeing by myself, but what do you mean by new tab or windows ?

Comment: Sorry. Yes I mrans no new tab in the browser or no new browser. Just new page in iframe 'Main'

Comment: okay do one thing, save the source code by running `print(driver.page_source)` code,  and save that into a text file, then upload that text file using file sharing website (free ofcourse). they will give you a sharable link. That link you can give us or share with us here.

Comment: I'm waiting for you.
And I don't understand why people who don't help block my writing.
I just want to solve the problem.

Comment: yes I understand that, I have not received any mail from you either. Do let me know how when you send me the email. also use @ to reply, otherwise I won't get the notification.

Comment: @cruisepandey ok I'm very sorry I sent the email normally. My e-mail address is 06server@naver.com.

Comment: @cruisepandey I sent it to 2 emails and the receipt was confirmed as soon as I sent it. If it still hasn't arrived, I think you've taken some action on your email or been blocked by overseas email.

Comment: Check out the below answer, there was  another frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's another frame,

```
<frame src="/core?attribute=coreMain&amp;fake=1629787283080" name="coreMain" id="coreMain">
```

so you need to switch again like below :

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(50)
driver.get("https://sugang.gwnu.ac.kr/")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 50)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "Main")))
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "id"))).send_keys('****')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "pwd"))).send_keys('****')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "btn_login"))).click()

wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "coreMain")))
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "menu_sugang"))).click()

print('Operation done !')
```

Comment: I feel sorry for my ignorance.
I only looked up iframe and didn't know that I put the frame syntax when I added the internal iframe.
I couldn't sleep because of this problem for a few days. I'm so glad it's settled now.
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript to execute clicks.

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].click()")
```

Use the correct class and tag names to target the right elements to navigate.

Comment: I don't get this, why would you wanna click on iframe ?

Comment: It's just an example. Please read what I mentioned just below the code. I told him to use the appropriate tag and class name to click the button to navigate to the next page.

Comment: He is looking for right locators, so this answer does not fulfil the exact requirement to answer this question.

Comment: I guess that we can't give an exact solution, because we don't know how the website works after he logs in.